# why max width changes on small screens

Tags: css, sass

When I give max-width of 1440px to a Header, and my whole screen is smaller than 1440px, in the browser this Header takes a width of 920px instead of 1440px.
Why does it do that ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

max-width is just the maximal width an element can have - there is no limit on how small it can be. For that you use min-width.

Try setting width as well as max-width to 1440px. If that doesn't work, add min-width too.

Answer (score 0):

You say your whole screen in smaller than 1440px, it would be logical for the header to take a smaller width, since a width of 1440px is not possible..

Otherwise I don't understand your question very well.. Maybe take a look at padding and margins. Or share your code for a better answer.

Comment: Its actually a simple question, there is no margin or padding involved, I just gave max-width 1440px to the Header and on the browser this same Header gets 920px, but the whole VW of the screen is 1366px.
And I was wondering if it ll get bigger when the app is used on bigger screens

Comment: with the information I have right now that would be the case. It will get bigger if the screen is bigger (until the max-width is achieved). Additionally if your screen can handle items with a max width of 1366px (which I don't know is the case) it should get a width of 1366px. So if that is the case please add more information, like your code, so I can help. If it isn't the case I hope I answered your question